# Hadoop FileFormat for Null fields

Tags: csv, hadoop, binary, hbase, avro

I was thinking of storing below CSV file in any format available in HDFS.

```
        H1  H2  H3  H4     

Row1    1   NA  8.6 65
Row2    2   NA  NA  56
Row3    4.6 7.5 NA  65
```

I know it's very easy we can present this easily in Hbase by skipping qualifier for specific row. I am looking for any file format like this available, So that we can skip saving NA in file and have pointer to this somewhere else(Metadata) instead keeping NA.